# Function call if the second parameter is given null, the third parameter is giving as a second parameter?

Tags: perl, function

I am a newbie in perl, I have defined a function

```
sub ex_arg($_)
{
    print "$_[0]\n";
    print "$_[1]\n";
    print "$_[2]\n";
}
1;
```

in another page i am calling that page.

```
require "ex_arg.pl";
ex_arg(1,2,3);
ex_arg(1,,3);  #in the second function i want the second parameter to be null
1;
```

is it possible to do this. am not getting the second parameter instead the third parameter is coming as the second parameter.

Am i doing something wrong. please correct me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that your argument list does not retain an empty value for the second argument before it is passed to the subroutine. The list `1,,3` will expand into the same list as `1,3`.

You'll need to pass some value that actually exists, such as `undef` or the empty string.

```
ex_arg(1, undef, 3);
```

Then perhaps something like

```
sub ex_arg {
    my ($arg1, $arg2, $arg3) = @_;
    if (! defined($arg2)) {            # checking if arg2 is empty
        # do something
    }
}
```

On a related note, you should not use prototypes in your subroutine declaration unless you know what it does. They are used to create specific behaviour in subroutines, and it has nothing to do with how other languages work, with regard to variables in the subroutine.

```
sub foo ( ... ) {
       #^^^^^^^----- prototypes

sub foo {      # this is the standard way to declare
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
ex_arg(1, undef, 3);
```

`ex_arg(1, , 3)` for perl is same thing as `ex_arg(1, 3)`

```
perl -MO=Deparse -e 'ex_arg(1, , 3);'
ex_arg(1, 3);   # <<<<<< deparsed
```

---

Side notes; if you don't want to use [**prototypes**](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes) then `sub ex_arg {..}` is what you want.

Prefer `my ($x,$y) = @_;` over `$_[0]` and `$_[1]`.